# Will these wire wheels fit my Honda Accord?

Tags: wheels

I'm in the market for a bit of Tokyo drift. I got some wheels I like the look of. Details of which can be found [here.](https://thewheelsmith.net/wheel-catalog/wire-wheels/chrome-hot-rod-wire-wheels). The Honda I have seen has the tyre specification 235/45 R18 was wondering which set of wires would fit best?